# JaVers in multi tenant architecture

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, multi-tenant, javers

I need to integrate my application with Javars. But, my application is multi tenant.
I am trying to integrate JaVers mongodb. I succeded in integrating JaVers. But, when the app is started, JaVers storing it's collections jv_snapshots and jv_head_id in the ***test database***. If I delete the test db and again start the application, still the test db is automatically created and the test db would use by the JaVers.

So, How can I tell JaVers to use my own DB in a multi tenant architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using Javers' Spring Boot starter:

```
def mongoRepository = new MongoRepository(MongoClients.create().getDatabase("my_database"))
javers = javers().registerJaversRepository(mongoRepository).build()
```

If you are using Javers' Spring Boot starter, Javers will automatically connect to your application's database.

And there is no notion of *tenant* in Javers. All you can do is to create one Javers instance per tenant or more generally one Javers instance per one db configuration.

Comment: Why is it connect to test db then?